# What is role of config.js in Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UwKuPLTntKRAXAY2dGAx?p=preview)

I'm learning angular2 (I do have angular1 background). While learning Angular2, I came across above mentioned example.

1) I don't understand usage of config.js. Moreover, I'd like to gain knowledge of "map" object used in config.js.

2) I've been trying to export "Friend" Module written in friend.ts file. but somehow I'm not able to export it or I don't know how to export it. look at below code,

**app.ts**

```
import {bootstrap, Component, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2'
import {FirstComponent} from './first'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',

 template:"<div>Hello Angular2</div>"
})
class AppComponent { }

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

**first.ts**

```
import {bootstrap, Component, CORE_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/angular2';

export FirstComponent{

  console.log("FirstComponent exported");
}
```

Your little guidance will teach me so many things for angular2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The map object in 'config.js' is used to substitue a module with another based on the current module location, like an alias.

The role of map is well explain here: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-map

2) I think that the problem is that you didn't specify the ***class*** keyword. Because a component is basically a class.

To tell the compiler that you are creating a component you must also decorate the class with the Component decorator.

```
export class FirstComponent { ... }
```

Comment: oops! still not working. I think you should modify my plunker.

Comment: See the following link for my corrected version of your plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/kgQ4yS3VyXc9m3sor8zH?p=preview

I've commented out where I made change. Hope it will help !

Comment: I appreciate your answer. just last thing, would you please help me to identify why my FirstComponent is not getting called according to this plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/kjNHNvbi8IrCLFinn9o3?p=preview

Comment: I maybe miss something but I don't see where you call it so I think that is the problem.

Comment: should it be './first' or 'first' or something else? I can't understand that part.

Comment: just because of config.js, its getting tougher for me.

Comment: I modify your plnkr, and comment it out here is the link: http://plnkr.co/edit/AUOy8Qw5WzuXJNHBctLh?p=preview

Comment: its not working. still you have put great explanation.

Comment: Explain me what you don't understand and I will do my best to explain it to you.

Comment: Your plunker is still not working. pls help me to make it work in my way. your way is appreciated and understood. but still I what know why it is not working as expected.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I miss to add template field in firstComponnent. Now it will work: http://plnkr.co/edit/XfbHEEqaaQ7lJ4Hcuc9N?p=preview

Comment: I create a new plnkr, where I explain everything I did and why I did it, hope it will help because I can't do better. http://plnkr.co/edit/CKZ2l9WqMljXM1FO0IoF?p=preview

Comment: again nice explanation. thanks a lot for it. but what you are doing here is, you put everything in src folder. I want to put everything out of src folder means no src folder. Everything lies in root directory. Now difficulty is with that config.js settings I don't know why its not working for me. may be I'm wrong somewhere or something else. but I want that to work without src folder. I hope I'm clear this time. but man you explanation is superb.

Comment: @Romain could be please explain bit more about need of config.json ? after reading your answer still not clear.